# How to use single function pointer to call multiple functions?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int, int);
int sub(int, int);
int mul(int, int);

int sum(int a, int b) {
    return (a + b);
}

int sub(int a, int b) {
    return (a - b);
}

int mul(int a, int b) {
    return (a * b);
}

int main() {
    int (*fptr)(int, int);
    fptr = &sum;
    int val = (fptr)(2,v3);
    printf("Sum: %d", val);
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, I want to use the same `fptr` to call all the 3 functions (`sum`, `sub` and `mul`). How can I do this?

Comment: Change `return (a*b)''` to `return (a*b);`  fptr can only hold one value at a time just like any other variable.  You could make it an array to hold all three.

Comment: `fptr = sum; fptr(1, 2); fptr = sub; fptr(1, 2); fptr = mul; fptr(1, 2);`

Comment: You can assign different pointer *values* to the same object, `fptr`, and use `fptr` to call whichever function its current value points to at the time of the call.  But any given pointer value, if valid, identifies exactly one function for the entire run of the program.

Comment: @IndyRose What is v3 in this expression fptr)(2,v3)?

Comment: "How to use single function pointer to call multiple functions?" How does that even make sense? Surely you'll want to call them in sequence, not all at once (which would be impossible without multithreading). If so simply toss them into an array and run through it with a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
int main() {
  static const struct
  {
    int (*fptr)(int, int);   // pointer to function
    const char* name;        // name of fucntion
  } table[] = {
    {&sum, "Sum" },
    {&sub, "Sub" },
    {&mul, "Mul" },
    {NULL, "" }             // terminator to mark the end of the table array
  };

  for (int i = 0; ; i++)
  {
    int (*func)(int, int) = table[i].fptr; // get function pointer
    const char* funcname = table[i].name;  // get function name

    if (func == NULL)      // is it NULL => we're at the end
      break;

    int val = func(2, 3);  // call the function

    printf("%s: %d\n", funcname, val);  // print name of function and result
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A function pointer is just that: a pointer.

If you have this

```
        int mul(int, int);
```

you can then write

```
    int op1 = 2;
    int op2 = 3;
    int (*function)(int, int) = NULL;  // a function pointer
    function                  = mul;   // its use
```

And use it as

```
    printf(
        "%d*%d = %d\n", op1, op2,
        function(op1, op2) // calls 'mul'
    );
```

#### using a single pointer to call multiple functions

Here `F` is an array of pointers to these kind of functions, initialized to point to the 3 functions in the question

```
    int (*F[])(int, int) = {sum, sub, mul};
    printf(
        "(%d * %d) = %d\n", op1, op2,
        F[2](op1, op2));  // calls 'mul'
    F[2] = sub;
    printf(
        "(%d - %d) = %d\n", op1, op2,
        F[2](op1, op2));  // now calls 'sub'
```

And get

```
(2 * 3) = 6
(2 - 3) = -1
```

As you see you can assign a new value just by using the name of the function

Sure, as [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77928623/11234199) you can use some encapsulation and write

```
typedef struct
{
    const char* name;
    const char* operator;
    int (*F)(int, int);
} Example;
```

And write

```
    // using the Example thing
    Example vft[] = {
        {"Sum", "+", sum},
        {"Sub", "-", sub},
        {"Mul", "*", mul},
        {"operation", "operator", NULL}  // just a sentinel
    };
    Example* p = vft;
    while (p->F != NULL)
    {
        printf(
            "[%s]\t(%d %s %d) = %d\n", p->name, op1,
            p->operator, op2, p->F(op1, op2)),
            ++p;
    }
```

And get

```
[Sum]   (2 + 3) = 5
[Sub]   (2 - 3) = -1
[Mul]   (2 * 3) = 6
```

#### a complete example

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77928623/how-to-use-single-function-pointer-to-call-multiple-functions
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    const char* name;
    const char* operator;
    int (*F)(int, int);
} Example;

int sum(int, int);
int sub(int, int);
int mul(int, int);

int main(void)
{
    int op1 = 2;
    int op2 = 3;
    int (*function)(int, int) = NULL;  // a function pointer
    function                  = mul;   // its use
    printf(
        "%d*%d = %d\n", op1, op2,
        function(op1, op2) // calls 'mul'
    ); 

    // using the Example thing
    Example vft[] = {
        {"Sum", "+", sum},
        {"Sub", "-", sub},
        {"Mul", "*", mul},
        {"operation", "operator", NULL}  // just a sentinel
    };
    Example* p = vft;
    while (p->F != NULL)
    {
        printf(
            "[%s]\t(%d %s %d) = %d\n", p->name, op1,
            p->operator, op2, p->F(op1, op2)),
            ++p;
    }

    int (*F[])(int, int) = {sum, sub, mul};
    printf(
        "(%d * %d) = %d\n", op1, op2,
        F[2](op1, op2));  // calls 'mul'
    F[2] = sub;
    printf(
        "(%d - %d) = %d\n", op1, op2,
        F[2](op1, op2));  // now calls 'sub'

    return 0;
}

int sum(int a, int b) { return (a + b); }
int sub(int a, int b) { return (a - b); }
int mul(int a, int b) { return (a * b); }
```

That shows

```
2*3 = 6
(Sum): 2+3 = 5
(Sub): 2-3 = -1
(Mul): 2*3 = 6
(2 * 3) = 6
(2 - 3) = -1
```